# CSS Title / Header Right Side Border Line With Box Padding

Tags: html, css

How to bring the right padding of the box without any extra {div}. The title ::after Selector should admire the right padding of the box. Here is my code. How to do that?

**Quentin Veron gave me the right solution.**

```css
.box {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 18px;
  border-left: 8px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; // This is very important
}

.title:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.title:after {
  margin-right: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h3 class="title">Title Right Border Line</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: relative;` on **.title**.

Comment: Inserting position: relative; at the title does not work.

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` too.

Comment: Thanks It worked by adding ''overflow: hidden'' to the .title css.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.box {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 18px;
  border-left: 8px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-color: #000;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h3 class="title" style="">Title Right Border Line</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: If you write any content below the title also goes at the position of the title.                                                                             <div class="box">
  <h3 class="title">Title Right Border Line</h3>

  The Content Part..... 
</div>